# How many elements are there in the set R?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

+Let
A
be a finite set with
$n \geq 4$ elements and let
R
be an equivalence relation on
A
.
Suppose that there are exactly
$n-2$ equivalence classes and that no equivalence class can
contain exactly three elements. Recall that the elements of the set
R
are ordered pairs of
elements from
A.

I know the answer is $n+4$ but I don't see the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pidgeonhole principle to figure out exactly how many elements are in each equivalence class. In particular, if you (correctly) answer the two questions:

- Can there be any equivalence class with *more than* $3$ elements?
- How many equivalence classes *must* have exactly $2$ elements?

Then you know pretty much everything about the structure of the relation. Then, notice that $R$ is just the set of pairs which come from the same equivalence class - so for, instance, an equivalence class of size $2$ is represented by $2^2=4$ elements in $R$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not $n-4$.  Our group of $n$ people will be divided into $n-2$ groups, of which $n-4$ will be groups of $1$, and $2$ are groups of $2$.
The $4$ people who will have company can be cosen in $\binom{n}{4}$ ways, and for each such way the chosen $4$ can be divided into $2$ groups of $2$ in $3$ ways.